# Can autowiring is possible in Spring with more than one references but a bean need to use only 1 of the references

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I am very new to spring and I was learning Auto-wiring.
Go a doubt that what if I have a bean which is referring to other , but my bean config file is having more than one reference. how to handle such scenario ?
I have a bean

```
<bean id="tableModel" class="quiz.client.PhoneBookTableModel" />
<bean id="nameTextField" class="quiz.client.PhoneBookTextField" />
<bean id="phoneTextField" class="quiz.client.PhoneBookTextField" />

<bean id="mainFrame" class="quiz.client.PhoneAppMainFrame"
    init-method="createGUI">
    <property name="frameWidth">
        <value>500</value>
    </property>
    <property name="frameHeight">
        <value>600</value>
    </property>
    <property name="frameTitle">
        <value>Phone Book App</value>
    </property>
    <property name="nameTextField">
        <ref bean="nameTextField" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="mainPanel" class="quiz.client.PhoneBookUIPanel"
    init-method="init">
    <property name="inputPanel">
        <ref bean="inputPanel" />
    </property>
    <property name="tableModel">
        <ref bean="tableModel" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now one property is expecting the reference of nameTextField and other is expecting tableModel.
So how can I manage auto-wiring.
Does both the main property holder class needed to have a setter for all the references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use autowire="byName" in bean tag.

See [this](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/08/spring-bean-autowire-byname/)